# Ajax call failing; xhr.responseXML is undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a simple ajax call:

> When the user selects and option, some info about that option will be
>   echoed into a div (this is dynamic)

Here's my code for the ajax call

**ajax.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
//Add Event 
    //Currently Broadcasting @Zone 
    $('#beacon0').on('change', function () 
    {
        var Selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        var SelectedText   = Selected.text();
        var SelectedEncoded = encodeURIComponent(SelectedText);

        $.ajax
        ({
        url:        'ajax-addevent.php',
        data:       'n_beacon='+ SelectedEncoded,
        dataType:   'JSON',
        success: function(returnClass)
            {
                var resultajax = jQuery.parseJSON(returnClass)
                console.log(resultajax);
            },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) 
            {
                var errors = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log("failed");
                console.log (errors);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

SO the ajax call should give the name of the zone in the URL, so I can $_GET the parameter in my php script. This is the php I run just to test the ajax call.

**ajax-addevent.php**

```
<?php
include("classes/event.class.php");

$event = new Event();
$GetZoneName = $_GET['n_beacon'];
$ZoneName = urldecode($GetZoneName);
$arrayDetails = $event->getBeaconEvent($ZoneName);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($arrayDetails))
{
        $EventTitle = $row["n_title"];
        $EventLink = $row["n_link"];
        $EventDate = $row["n_date"];
}
        $arr = array( "EventTitle" => $EventTitle,
                           "EventLink" => $EventLink, 
                           "EventDate" => $EventDate );

        header("content-type:application/json");

        $json_arr = json_encode($arr);

        return $json_arr;
?>
```

My problem is that the ajax call fails and gives me this as result:

[image: Error]

What's wrong why my ajax call? Can you help?

**EDIT Update Code:**

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get an XML response when the returned datatype is JSON - xhr.responseXML will always be undefined unless the response is valid XML.

Try using xhr.responseText instead. You can use JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) to get a javascript object out of it.

Another good technique is to use the dev tools of your current browser to inspect the network response directly (F12 in Firefox or Chrome, then open the Network tab).

Comment: now I get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when I select an option. It links to the add_event.php (the page where the ajax call happens). the only thing that's on line 1 is "<?php"

Comment: Looks like the browser thinks it's getting XML back. Try adding the following to your PHP to set the content type of the response:
    header("content-type:application/json");

Comment: Hey, I followed your adivce and updated the question, could you check it out if you have the time, since I still get errors :(

Comment: Your JSON is ill-formed. Have a look in the network tab in Chrome, look for the call to `ajax-addevent.php` and post the response here.

Comment: No response there; http://puu.sh/ip44V/02e7188122.png . I figured it was the php (I forgot urldecode) but that doesn't work, i'll update the code.

Comment: Try visiting the php script with your browser (i.e. go to `http://your.server/ajax-addevent.php?n_beacon=<something_encoded>`). What do you get back?

Comment: I used a var dump on the array $arr (not encoded to json) and it shows it without any problem http://puu.sh/ip4Po/1ca9b9cc64.png

Comment: I have a feeling it's the JSON encoding that's the problem. Can you dump the array after encoding?

Comment: got this result: string(81) "{"EventTitle":"10 Jaar IMD","EventLink":"www.howest.be","EventDate":"2015-06-19"}"

Comment: Is that what you get when you visit the php script with the browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80536/discussion-between-user3589409-and-duncan-thacker).

Comment: Yes, it's when I visit the script. I think we'll have to use chat since we might have to much comments